# difference between controlling the flow with if and elif

Tags: python, control-flow

i was running a program that return the maximum 2 number in a certain list

and I found that there a difference between using if and elif in definition of function

So if i used :

```
def maxi (lst) :
    max_pos1 = 0 
    max_pos2 = 1 
    if lst[max_pos1] < lst [max_pos2] :
        max_pos1 , max_pos2 = 1 , 0 
    for x in range (len(lst)) :
        if lst[max_pos1] < lst [x] :
            max_pos1 , max_pos2 = x , max_pos1 
        if lst [max_pos2] < lst [x] :
            max_pos2 = x 
    return lst[max_pos1] , lst[max_pos2]

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,77,14,15,16]
print(maxi(lst))
```

The output will be :

```
(77, 77)
```

Which is not correct in my opinion

but if i changed if in the 9 line to elif as follow :

```
def maxi (lst) :
    max_pos1 = 0 
    max_pos2 = 1 
    if lst[max_pos1] < lst [max_pos2] :
        max_pos1 , max_pos2 = 1 , 0 
    for x in range (len(lst)) :
        if lst[max_pos1] < lst [x] :
            max_pos1 , max_pos2 = x , max_pos1 
        elif lst [max_pos2] < lst [x] :
            max_pos2 = x 
    return lst[max_pos1] , lst[max_pos2]

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,77,14,15,16]
print(maxi(lst))
```

The output will be :

```
(77, 16)
```

which the result i hoped for , can any one explain why this change happened in the output ?

Comment: See this link for a brief explanation. `else` and `elif` catch results which don't meet an `if` criteria, while two concurrent `if`s will both be executed if their conditions are met, regardless of the result of the other.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_else.asp

Answer (score 0):

`if ...elif...else` is one control flow, only one condition in this flow will satisfy and data can be changes

`if ..elif..else` and then `if ..elif ..else`, are two different control flow and 2 condition change will hapen

in first code case, it is 2 control flow, in second one only 1 control flow

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that makes sense.  If you have two `if` statements both will execute regardless if the first condition was met or not.  If you use `if` followed by `elif` the `elif` statement will only be checked if the first `if` condition was *not* met.